# Having issue showing image returning from database with $.post() jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm retrieving a table from database as result of a search action, but when I try to display the result I see the table and the data, but the image returned in each row is not render, I think my problem is in the $('#search').html(data), I'm not sure please someone knows what is the problem?

this is the result

http://s9.postimg.org/mro5qn46n/search_result.jpg

****This is the search page, where result table is displayed****

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
     <td>
     <label for="criteria">Select Criteria</label>
     </td>
    <td>
       <select name="select" id="criteria">
           <option selected="true" style="display:none;"></option>              
           <option value="value1">name</option> 
           <option value="value2">apartment</option>
      </select>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" name="value" size="40" maxlength="60" id="value"\>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
      <input name="name-submit" type="button" id="submit" value="Search"\>

  </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td >
  <div id="search"></div>
  </td>
  </tr> 
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){

    var criteria = $("#criteria option:selected").text();
    var    value = $("#value").val();

    $.post("search_r.php",{criteria:criteria,value:value},function(data){

        $('#search').html(data);

          });

    });

</script>
```

****This is the Page that calls $.post() in the main seach page ****

```
<?php
$criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
  $value = $_POST['value'];

      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysqli_select_db($con,"gables");

   $query = "SELECT * FROM residents WHERE $criteria = '$value'";       
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Apartment</th>
<th>Parking</th>
<th>Phone1</th>
<th>Phone2</th>
<th>image</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['0'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['5'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['6'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td><img src=get_image.php?id=".$row['0']." width=160 height=120/></td>";   
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


?>
```

***Here the get_image.php****

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
       mysqli_select_db($con,"gables");

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM residents WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result)
$picture = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

echo $picture['11'];

?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), you have absolutely **NO** error handling and are simply assuming all of your DB operations can never fail. Did you check if you connected to the db properly? Did you check if your query didn't fail? Did you check what got returned if it did actually run?

Comment: what u are doing in get_image.php file `

Comment: what do you do with get_image.php?id= and why dont you store the url of the image in db and echo it in img tag

Comment: I set a static query and I load the search_r.php directly and see well the table an image, but when I call the search_r.php from the $.post() and use $('#search').html(data) the image is not render, this is why i think the problem is in the $.post(), I'm doing something must be other way.

Comment: checkout this `echo "<td><img src='get_image.php?id=".$row['0']."' width=160 height=120/></td>";`

Comment: I think u can get image link like this. check html code in browser it shuld be empty according to your code

Comment: Harshama there isn't problem there, i checked passing static value to get_image.php and search_r.php and I loaded each page directly and it return values correctly and see image too,        my problem is when i use funtion $.post() it return the table with image missing

Comment: get_image.php file returns the url of the image ?

Comment: Marc B I load search_r.php directly whith a static query in a browser and it shows correctly image and everything in the table. so the problem is something in the $.post() or .hmlt() maybe this is no the correct way for image

Comment: Harshama the get_image.php return an image content to the search_r.php to be loaded as you see

Comment: can u put the get_image files code in here. you can't get image url like this. I'm sure ...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can chage the `get_image.php` file as this. Then this work will work.

```
<?php
function get_image($id){
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
       mysqli_select_db($con,"gables");

$query = "SELECT * FROM residents WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result)
$picture = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
return $picture['11'];
}
?>
```

Then use `require_once();` function and in image src like this.`echo "<td><img src='".get_image($row['0'])."' width=160 height=120/></td>";`. In your code check how the src path will print and it will be print like as echo string, not as a execute the file.

```
echo 

    "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Apartment</th>
    <th>Parking</th>
    <th>Phone1</th>
    <th>Phone2</th>
    <th>image</th>
    </tr>";
    require_once('search_r.php');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['0'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['5'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['6'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td><img src='".get_image($row['0'])."' width=160 height=120/></td>";   
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Harshana please where i have to use require_once(); and about the echo in src image, Could you write what i have to remplace, I apreciate your help

Comment: @Jaisniel check the solution i have edited the solution.

Comment: @Harshana I did exactly what you ask me but the issue. http://s9.postimg.org/mro5qn46n/search_result.jpg

Comment: @Jaisniel what is the issue ?

Comment: @Jaisniel can u put the html code for the not displied image from browser source code.

Comment: @Harshana Do try and use full words as some people do not know English well enough to know all the shorthand.